# Scrolling issues in a TextBox used inside a ListBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

Since    `TextBox`    doesn't allow smooth scrolling, I've used it as a   `ListBoxItem`. It works great. But when I enter many lines, the cursor goes out of the view, down below the list box, because of it I'm unable to see the text which I am typing. To see the cursor, I have to manually swipe the `TextBox` up.

Here's the code:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Items>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                 Width="467"
                 AcceptsReturn="True"
                 MinHeight="300"
                 MaxHeight="Infinity"
                 />
    </ListBox.Items>
 </ListBox>
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What UI do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the height of the TextBox and wrap a ScrollViewer around your TextBox. That has worked for me!

Comment: Now I've added the TextBox into a ListBox with infinite height. It works much better than the ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the srollable textblock instead of textbox..For more details

visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx